# URL of image not saved into database

Tags: laravel

I am trying to add an image to profile in my application. The code returns the correct URL and also the image is stored into the specified folder. But the URL is not saved into the database[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ6yI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I see two things :

1 - You move your picture with `public_path()` and you set the $url with `URL::to()` which is not really logic. Try this way :

```
$url = public_path() . '/profile_photo/'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
```

2 - At the end of your `if` statement, your set an `exit()` method, which exit from your method. Take it off !

EDIT ----

To save it to your db, do this way :

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->profile_photo = $url;
$user->save();
```

Comment: Thank you ! But still the problem is not solved. The url is not saves to database

Comment: i've added the save part to my answer

Comment: Thank you for this. It works. But why don't you use update()

Comment: save acts like an update if you provide the model ID and acts like an insert if not. That's why i always use `save()`

Comment: How I delete a file from folder when I upload a new file in laravel 5.4